# Creating a React and React Native component in a single npm package

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, cross-cutting-concerns

Is it possible to create a component, living in a single npm package, that would work in both React and React Native?

I have created two variations of a component (`View` vs `div` and so on), one for the web and one for react native. I could easily use a build script or something like preprocessor.js to build a react or react-native output of the library but is there a better way?

Have anyone had any luck building a component that you could simply `npm install` into a react or react native project and just have it use the correct implementation? Or would I have a problem where both the `react` and `react-native` dependencies would exist in my `package.json`? Thanks!